# Material UI DatePicker set to Required

Tags: reactjs

i am using the Material UI DatePicker in my react app and need to set the date to be required?

Do I need to create a custom validator checking value on submit or is there a prop I can use to set field to required?

```
<DatePicker
            spacing={2}
            PopoverProps={{ container: this.props.container }}
            onChange={this.updateEndDate}
            value={this.state.endDate}
            initialFocusedDate={this.state.startDate}
            minDate={this.state.startDate}
            disablePast="true"
            disableToolbar="true"
            variant="inline"
            label="End Date"

           // I have tried adding required, required="true", required={true}


          />
```

Comment: What have you tried? Could you show us some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `required` attribute/prop on the material-ui/date-picker. What can be done is to set a default date say today. And handle the error/required criteria `onChange`.

Comment: what about adding this prop to Autocomplete`renderInput={(inputProps) => ( <TextField {...inputProps} required/>)}`

Answer (score 14):

You can set required in a DatePicker by adding the slotProps prop for textfield (you can read more about it in the mui component API section for datepicker):

```
<DatePicker
        spacing={2}
        PopoverProps={{ container: this.props.container }}
        onChange={this.updateEndDate}
        value={this.state.endDate}
        initialFocusedDate={this.state.startDate}
        minDate={this.state.startDate}
        disablePast="true"
        disableToolbar="true"
        variant="inline"
        label="End Date"

       // I have tried adding required, required="true", required={true}

        slotProps={{
              textField: {
                required: true,
              },
            }}
      />
```

though it won't show any errors, it sticks with the required property.
I'll update the answer if I find a way to add the inherited required dialogue box to it

Answer (score 0):

Given that the value of the input is monitored using `endDate`, set `helperText` and `error` to update the UI for the input in an error condition.

```js
const requiredError = endDate === '' || endDate === undefined
const helperText = requiredError ? 'Input is required' : undefined
<DatePicker
  ... // other attributes
  helperText={helperText}  // this is almost right
  error={requiredError}
/>
```

But, if you specify `helperText` or `error`, then you will override other date format checking error messages that the input will display, so you can do it this way:

```js
const errorProps = requiredError ? {
  helperText: 'Input is required',
  error: true
} : { }

<DatePicker
  ... // other attributes
  // Preserve date format checking
  // Provide force error properties only if failing required test
  { ...errorProps } 
/>
```

Note, using the `KeyboardDatePicker` from @material-ui/pickers v 3.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem adding required in TextField params:

```js
  <DatePicker
    variant="outlined"
    label="My date"
    value={myDate}
    onChange={(date) => setMyDate(date)}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} required />}
  />
```